# What to do with a highly voted, rotten, link only *question*?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Looking at Haskell's top questions I noticed this particular question: [Small Haskell program compiled with GHC into huge binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115459/small-haskell-program-compiled-with-ghc-into-huge-binary).

This question is very peculiar:

1. question and answer have many upvotes (80+ and 140+ respectively)
2. the text of the question is completely useless. Here's the *complete* quote of it:

   > My source code can be found here: https://github.com/tm1rbrt/S3DM
   >
   > When I compile it with `ghc test.hs` the executable comes out at over 7
   >   meg! What, if anything, can I do to reduce this?

   Note: *the github link is broken*. I've tried to use the Wayback machine, but it doesn't have that page available. I tried searching the user on Github, but no user is found with that name.

   Also, the answers don't contain any of the code that was linked by the question.
3. The answer is *still* useful. Reading it it's clear what the problem was (although not how exactly to reproduce it) and tells you how to solve the space problem mentioned in the question.

Now, what should we do with that question (a part from poking the author to edit the code in)?

1. Should we just let it alone, even though it doesn't have any mean of verifying the claim they make?
2. Edit out any reference to concrete code and make it a "GHC creates big executables, especially when using library X, Y. Why?" question?
3. Create a brand-new MWE that show the behaviour described by the question and answer and edit it into the question?
4. Close the question as *"**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**"*

Also, what should we do in the general case?

In this case, it seems like option 3 might be viable because the problem was simple and the answer contains a lot of information that can be used to reverse-engineer some code. However what should we do in such a situation when option 3 *cannot* be achieved?

Comment: The user behind the GitHub account is [still active on SE sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689303/linqdatasource-where-field-as-selected-in-gridview). Small comfort if they are ignoring the pings though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes. I added a comment to the question to ask him to fix this (an other user already poked him 2 days ago). I was asking in the case he isn't able to retrieve the code (which might be). In fact, if he's active option 4 may be the most reasonable to let him know that the question has something wrong...

Comment: I'd say option 4 is very much applicable here. The post won't be deleted, but closing it would be entirely appropriate.

Comment: Not sure if related, but perhaps the S3DM repo was a clone of https://github.com/klkblake/s3dm? Sourcegraph [thinks they are](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/klkblake/s3dm/.contributors).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Uhm... given that the question is about *Haskell* and that repository contains *Go* code I doubt that... although it may have been an Haskell translation of those files.

Comment: Sure, just trying to trace this; Sourcegraph reuses Github data. See https://sourcegraph.com/tm1rbrt@-x-x5AYOTSTuGEEXyA= for example, as well as https://github.com/klkblake/s3dm/commits/master?page=2

Comment: @MartijnPieters Weird, I tried to dig up the code, but all I find is Go code. Is the question on Go, or I am confused because S3DM is some math library that is used frequently with Go?

Comment: I can find references to both a https://github.com/tm1rbrt/s3dm and a https://github.com/tm1rbrt/s3dm-go, so I'm guessing the same author may have rewritten the Haskell bits as Go?

Comment: The [GitHub repository list](https://archive.org/details/archiveteam-github-repository-index-201212) from late 2012 shows that the repositories were already gone at that time, without any clones of the Haskell one. At least, none that were on GitHub and had s3dm in the name.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't notice this discussion. That old code was based on a go library i wrote before it but is long gone. The deleted that old Github account a while ago too and made a new one with my real name. I don't have a copy of that old code and it was awful anyway.

Comment: @tm1rbrt Aren't you able to produce a small program that reproduces the problem? As far as I understand it's a matter of remembering, more or less, which libraries were imported in the old code and write a minimal `main` function...

Answer (score 13):

I edited the question so that it, and its answers, will be clearer and more useful. At least I think I did. Let's see what happens next.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong mate. I initially voted to close the question (and it is now closed) because I thought the original question was a close-worthy case even though I am not much into Haskell. However if you are sure that this is a more generic problem then nominating the question for re-opening would be good. Are you sure about it (or) should we just leave it to the community to decide?

Comment: I am a member of the community and i expressed my view :-)

Comment: Thanks for responding mate. I see the post is now re-opened but it already has one close vote from somebody. Seems like the community is totally divided in opinions here. But that is normal :)

Answer (score 9):

It's not a link-only question, because it specifies the problem, however in quite a vague way: "I have a small program, which compiles to huge binary".

Although there are not enough details, and without checking the link it **might** be hard to say what is an issue, this is what one of Haskell experts have said:

> Haskell uses static linking by default. This is, the whole bindings to
>   OpenGL are copied into your program.

It looks, even without link, the question provided enough information for a Haskel expert to identify a problem, which is not specific, but quite generic. The question **might** be too broad or vague, but the answers have pinpointed the **exact** problem with static linking.

Comment: The edit you made has made the answer not really relevant to the question. This is a problem I see in generalizing the question. Now the answer is all about a phantom `test.hs`; it contains code to strip its symbols and shows changes in file size and linked libraries... however currently this is just noise (note: it's however *useful* to show how to strip the binaries and use dynamic linking).