# Flagging link-only questions

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

"[STATS 380 Binomial and Poisson Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837027/stats-380-binomial-and-poisson-distribution)" contains only a link to an image of a question (I haven't clicked on it to confirm). I understand that there is concern that users can [link to an image and later change the content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273032/should-i-edit-external-image-links-by-reuploading-on-imgur/273040#273040).

I am learning to use flags and don't have the rep to flag to close yet. Should I flag this as needs moderator attention and explain in the comment or as VLQ?

I read "[What to do with a highly voted, rotten, link only *question*?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270881/what-to-do-with-a-highly-voted-rotten-link-only-question)" on a popular link-only question (though the one I am pointing out here is far from popular and there are no answers). My concern is, as pointed out in the accepted answer for "[Do moderators want link-only answer flags, or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272982/do-moderators-want-link-only-answer-flags-or-not)", that flagging as needs moderator attention would be "taking time from mods while the community could have handled it." However, this is a low-traffic question so I'm not sure it will be handled by the community.

Comment: Maybe you should simply edit the question, to show the actual image (done so now).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can this user already do that?

Comment: @rene No, but I can, you can and the OP of this question can.

Comment: An even better one came in yesterday (for 10k users): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840294/what-number-this-program-is-trying-to-find

Comment: even an upvote can be found on the question ... sad

Comment: And now the link for this question is dead and I can't follow with apprehensive glee and snort derision at the poor question and answers :'(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, a scan of a homework assignment is not an appropriate question on Stack Overflow. If nothing else, it could be closed as

> Off topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

emphasis on placing information within the question, and not relying entirely on an external image. Even if the image is brought into the question, that question is unreadable by a portion of our audience (those using screen readers or other accessibility tools). Images can be supplements, but shouldn't be the entirety of the question.

I went with "unclear" on this one, because I wasn't even sure what we were supposed to answer with there.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson. Just to be clear- should a low rep user such as myself (cannot vote to close as off-topic) flag that kind of inappropriate question for moderator attention, as VLQ, or leave alone?

Comment: You can't vote to close, but you can flag it to show up in the close vote queue for the community to handle.  Flag -> "it should be closed for another reason" -> "off-topic because" -> select the close reason above.

Comment: Thanks @Troyen. I think I don't have that option yet-- so far I have 4 choices for flagging: spam, offensive, VLQ, or other (needs moderator attention). I assume the other flag options will show up as I get more rep.

Comment: Make sure you're checking on a question that isn't already closed.

Comment: I am sure I was checking on a question that isn't closed. When I look at one that is on hold or one that has accepted/upvoted answers I only get 3 choices (spam, offensive, other/needs moderator attention). Anyway, thanks for the advice all.

Comment: @LJW check again... while it isn't identified separately as a privilege, you can't flag to close a post until you have enough rep to comment (because some of those actions leave automatic comments).  It was decided to hide those options until you can comment (which comes at 50 rep - which looks like you just hit an hour ago.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sweet! I've now got the "it should be closed for another reason" option.