# How to handle a link only question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672832/obiee-prompt-default-value-based-in-drilled-result) asks a relevant question, but through the use of a link (mostly, there is *some* detail). At first I thought it was a very low rep user trying to creatively post an image, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If I were to edit the question to add in the relevant detail I am betting that my edit would get rejected because it would appear I was altering the question too significantly.

I did not think this question quite pertained as this was a low quality question and was homework: [Flagging link-only questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276635/flagging-link-only-questions). The outcome of that thread is to flag it as off topic, but I don't believe that is the correct choice here.

Perhaps I should just downvote the question and comment on why there is a downvote?

Comment: Close it as unclear what you are asking, which I've done.  If that link is down, the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: The link went to an oracle support site, whose links are typically fairly stable. But I understand closing as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Oracle support links could still fail. We shouldn't need to go to another site to get the details to answer.

Comment: Completely agree. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The best thing would be if the details were added to the question.

You can leave a comment asking the OP to do so, and explain that their question needs to contain all information, without relying on off-site sources. That also shows the OP how Stack Exchange works, it helps them to become better at asking questions.

If the OP doesn't edit the question, or if you don't want to wait for the OP to do so, you can edit in the details yourself. But, it is **very** important that you point out in the edit comment that the extra information came from the linked resource. Otherwise your edit suggestion will indeed get rejected, probably as "radical change".

The next best thing to do is to flag it.
"Unclear" is appropriate, as per @bluefeet's comment: if the link was lost, there would be very little information to properly answer the question.
"Too broad" would also be an option in some of these cases, as without more explanation, there might be too many possible answers.

Comment: I'd say the first suggestion should be to comment to the OP to edit in the details themselves and explain why they should do this, as the emphasis should be on educating them to include everything within the post.

Comment: @Tanner Agreed, edited that into the answer.