# Help center section for link-only questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, help-center

Do we have an official help or faq entry for link-only questions, and if not, shouldn't we have one?

I am talking about these questions:

> How do I solve the problem explained [*here*]. I have read this
>   [*tutorial*], but I have trouble understanding the third paragraph.

This question might be fine if the author explained the problem and where they are stuck in their own words. But as it is, this is obviously crap.

When I encountered such a question just now, I wanted to leave a link to the faq explaining this, but I was unable to find anything.

We do have a link policy for **debugging questions**, even if it is somewhat subtle:

> Off topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code
>   working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or
>   error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question
>   itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to
>   other readers.
>   [*emphasis mine*]

But I did not find anything applicable for non-debugging questions.

And in any case, the statement "*all questions should stand on their own, without external links*" really deserves its own help section with size 50 font and a blink tag, not just 4 words.

We have something about link-only answers on the page ["How do I write a good **answer**"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

> Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

But there is no such paragraph on the page ["How do I write a good **question**"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

I am requesting that we add such a paragraph, perhaps emphasising that all problems and encountered difficulties must be explained by the asker themselves, and simply copy-pasting a programming exercise instead of linking to it is not enough.

---

Related meta questions:

- [Flagging link-only questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276635/flagging-link-only-questions) and [What to do with a highly voted, rotten, link only *question*?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270881/what-to-do-with-a-highly-voted-rotten-link-only-question)

  Deal only with debugging questions
- [How to handle a link only question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290431/how-to-handle-a-link-only-question)

  Asks how to deal with link-only questions (downvote, edit, vote-to-close), but does not mention any faq entries.

Comment: [ask] is what I usually point to. It's pretty clear that you need to explain what you're asking about.

Comment: I think it could stand to be a bit more explicit. [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) has a paragraph about links, which could be taken almost verbatim for a start.

Comment: *"the statement "all questions should stand on their own, without external links" really deserves its own help section with size 50 font and a blink tag, not just 4 words."* +1000. Maybe make it red, too.

Comment: @CodyGray sometimes, external links are justified, so "without _any_ links" is a bit radical. The criterion is something like "must not require the material on the external links for understanding." Then still, there are occasional questions where a link contains large suplemental data that cannot be reduced to MCVE because the question is about the way to pinpoint something in it.

Comment: @ivan That's not what is meant. The important part is that the question must be able to stand on its own. External links are fine, but they cannot be essential to the question. If they were removed (or the pages they point to were to become inaccessible), the question should still be complete and answerable. Those "occasional questions" that you mention, though, are problematic and run afoul of this guideline. I've never seen one where the problem wasn't just the asker's laziness.

Comment: @CodyGray http://stackoverflow.com/a/28393797/648265 (the link leads to the answer that contains the actual solution process rather than end result). The problem was to find discrepancies in long generated data to be able to identify their source.

Comment: So your example is an answer that you had to edit two different times as you figured out what the person was asking, and where the answer was ultimately just a link to another Q&A? I'm sorry, I'm not seeing how that proves any exception to the general guidelines. I'm sure the person who asked the question appreciates the effort you put into it, but that's just not a good answer. (Nor is it especially relevant to what we were talking about, which were *questions* with *external* links.)

Comment: @CodyGray ... but don't forget the freehand circles!